# ASP.NET Core 2 - switch active directory user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

In my current project (ASP.NET Core 2.2) authentication is handled by Active Directory. That means if user "abc" is logged in on a PC, in my ASP.NET Core app I have User.Identity.Name = "domain\abc". Menus and forms look slightly different for different users.

The new requirement during testing is: "what does the app look like if you are user 'xyz'?". Which means even though you are logged in as user "abc" the app should behave as if you were user "xyz". I have no idea how to handle this and absolutely no knowledge about Authentication-Services, Middleware etc. in ASP.NET Core 2.

Can someone please point me to some code examples and tutorials regarding this requirement?

Comment: Would it work to use 'Run As' on a different browser instance and log in as another user?

Comment: The probelm is, that NTLM/Kerberos is not handled by Asp.Net core itself, but the webserver module `HTTP.sys`. The handshake used is out of the scope of the pipeline. The only approach I can think about is to implement a middleware that is inserted at the very beginning of the pipeline and replaces the identity as early as possible. But this is a highly risky undertaken in my opinion. It would be a built-in security hole. On the other hand, if somebody can act this way in the name of somebody elese... well... that is something I would never allow in an evónterprise environment.

Comment: @ZorgoZ It's usually allowed for testing environments. Not prod.

Comment: There's a few ways you can do this. Instead of logging in as other accounts, you could make new testing accounts that have the same permissions as the accounts you wanted to simulate. Just give them the same permissions. Or instead of reading the username from the place you were using, you could store it in a session variable or something similar - obviously this should be disabled outside a testing environment.